# Netbeans cordova generates index.html file incorrectly?

Tags: html, cordova, netbeans

This is the code pre-generated by netbeans when a new cordova application is run. Line number 5 throws an error in netbeans, saying that the keyword msapplication-tap-highlight is not registered. Also, in line 19, the file cordova.js does not exist in the cordova project. When i try run the application through an android emulator, it gives me a build failed message. Build failed message written below html file. I tried launching the html file in android emulator through the command line, but

```
/Users/Programming/Desktop/Coding/GenericApp/www/index.html: Permission denied
```

Also, the command "android" suggested at the bottom of the Build Failed message does nothing in my Terminal. Any suggestions on how to solve any of the above problems would be appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

ant -f /Users/Programming/Desktop/Coding/GenericApp/nbproject "-Dupdate.task.jar=/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/webcommon/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-cordova-projectupdate.jar" -Dandroid.project.activity=GenericApp -Dsite.root=www -Dstart.file=index.html -Dandroid.sdk.home=/Users/Programming/Library/Android/sdk -Dandroid.target.device.arg=emulate -Dcordova.version=4.2.0-0.0.0 -Denv.DISPLAY=:0.0 "-Dios.certificate.name=iPhone Developer" -Dandroid.build.target=android-21 -Dconfig=android sim-android
check-android-template:
check-cordova-version:
check-cordova-project:
upgrade-to-cordova-project:
create-android:
cordova -d platform add android
Creating android project...
Running command: /Users/Programming/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/create --cli /Users/Programming/Desktop/Coding/GenericApp/platforms/android com.coolappz.GenericApp GenericApp
Command finished with error code 1: /Users/Programming/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/create --cli,/Users/Programming/Desktop/Coding/GenericApp/platforms/android,com.coolappz.GenericApp,GenericApp
/Users/Programming/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
Hint: Run "android" from your command-line to open the SDK manager.
    at /Users/Programming/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:174:19
    at _fulfilled (/Users/Programming/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/Programming/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/Programming/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /Users/Programming/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/Programming/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
Error: /Users/Programming/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
/Users/Programming/Desktop/Coding/GenericApp/nbproject/build.xml:150: exec returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error`msapplication-tap-highlight` is false error in editor, it does not have any effect on if or how the application will be built.

The `Please install Android target "android-19".` is a message from Cordova, probably you need to download specific Android SDK for Android 4.4 (aka Android API level 19).

About the missing `cordova.js`, I think it is added to the project during build process by Cordova and imho no need to worry about that.

The permission error I have no idea :) But it would seem like the index.html has not correct permissions set.